# How can I compile GCC with a shared library?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I create shared library `libpl.so`.

I use this command to create connections:

```
ln -s libpl.so.1.0.1 libpl.so.1
ln -s libpl.so.1.0.1 libpl.so
```

And now I try to compile my program using:

```
gcc main.c -o main -L. -libpl
```

but I have errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libpl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I do to fix it? How can I compile it?

Comment: Close, but still doesn't work
./main: error while loading shared libraries: liblp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: if running fails during runtime do the following -

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:`pwd`"
```

works correctly.

Compile with:

```
gcc main.c -o main -L. -lpl
```

Run with:

```
./main
```

Answer (score 3):

This line should help:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libpl.so:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You should follow this tutorial [on shared libraries on Linux](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html). This tutorial may answer to all your questions.