# How to add C-Libraries in macOS Big Sur?

Tags: c, gcc, macos-big-sur, clib

I want to add a C-Library in order to include it in Code simply by typing:

```
#include <libname>
```

It works when I'm using the full path like so:

```
#include "path/to/lib.h"
```

Is there a way to add the lib to some kind of standard location, where gcc will find it?

I've tried the following but it didn't work for me:
[How to add default Include and Library path for gcc in Macos for bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40658240/how-to-add-default-include-and-library-path-for-gcc-in-macos-for-bash)

(both `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  and `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` are empty and copying all *.h-Files to /usr/local/ also didn't work.)

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: `#include<libname>` searches for a file named `libname` on the system include path. It's possible although highly unusual not to use a suffix for an include file (usually `.h` in C) -- perhaps that's what you're doing wrong? A minimal but complete example that shows the problem would be helpful for your question.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/cpp/Search-Path.html provides information about how gcc finds `#include`d files in both the `<>` and `""` forms

Comment: Remember you need *both* the library path and the include path for headers.

Comment: Re “copying all *.h-Files to /usr/local/ also didn't work”: Did you copy the `.h` files to `/usr/local` or to `/usr/local/include`? The latter is the correct location for header files.